# Can I daisy chain pushes between git repos?

Tags: git

I'd like to do this:

1. Have a bare git repo, call it AAA.
2. Have users in R&D clone AAA, do their work, and push commits back to AAA.
3. Have a bare clone of AAA, call it BBB. BBB is off on a different server.
4. Have a limited set of users in Division X clone from BBB do so some specific work, and push commits back to BBB,
5. Have changes arriving at BBB be pushed to AAA.

Is that possible? Or will I need to **pull** from BBB to AAA?

Comment: are you checking out from same branches ?

Comment: If you want to keep the two central repositories in sync then that begs the question: why are you even using two central repositories in the first place?  Push/pull between two bare repositories is somewhat complicated since there is no simple way to deal with divergent branches; merging isn't easily possible in a bare repository.  And due to the possibility of merges, automating such a sync task is inadvisable.